# Forces and moments on Massless link

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, forces, free-body-diagram

I am the TA for a dynamics class, and I've come across an odd problem where I can't explain/don't remember how to look up the answer to the problem. I have the following problem from an old solution manual that looks like the following: [image: picture of four bar mechanism]

In the description of the problem, links 2 and 4 are said to have mass, but link 3 is assumed to be massless. Force F is known and the objective is to solve for torque T2.

In the solution manual, the author has the following equations for link 3:

Sum of forces in x direction: $F_{23x} + F_{43x} = 0$

Sum of forces in y direction: $F_{23y} + F_{43y} = 0$

Sum of moments about A: $r_3 \times F_{43} = 0 \rightarrow r_3cos(\theta_3)F_{43y} - R_3sin(\theta_3)F_{43x} = 0$

$F_{23x}$ refers to the "x component of force from link 2 on link 3".

The force equations seem okay to me, but the moment equation seems fishy to me. What is the right way to deal with a massless, rigid link in a dynamics problem like this? Do I even need to write equations for this link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason massless links need to have no net force or moment is because an unbalanced force or moment would accelerate it infinitely.

Another way to think about this is to consider Euler's first law for a rigid body, $$\mathbf{F}_G = m \, \mathbf{a}_{G/O},$$ where $\mathbf{F}_G$ is the net force on the center of mass, and $\mathbf{a}_{G/O}$ is the inertial acceleration of the center of mass. (It does not matter where we consider the "center of mass" to be for a massless link.) If the body has no mass, the right hand side is zero, and the force on the body must sum to zero.

Similarly, for Euler's second law, $$\mathbf{M}_O = I_O \, \boldsymbol{\alpha},$$ where $\mathbf{M}_O$ is the sum of the moments about an inertial point $O$, $I_O$ is the mass moment of inertia about $O$, and $\boldsymbol{\alpha}$ is the angular acceleration of the body. A massless body has no moment of inertia, so the right hand side is zero, and the sum of the moments must also be zero.

As for why you need these equations for the massless link in this problem, it allows you to solve for three of the four unknown reaction forces on the link, and you will need both components of $\mathbf{F}_{23}$ to determine the moment about $G2$.

As an aside, I believe if $F_{43x}$ and $F_{43y}$ are oriented with $x$ and $y$ in the diagram, then the moment equation should be $$\ell \sin(60) \, F_{43x} + \ell \cos(60) \, F_{43y} = 0,$$ if $\ell$ is the length of $AB$ and the counterclockwise direction is positive.

Answer (score 0):

The massless link is a two-force member. Meaning it can carry only tangential forces and no moments. Like a rope, or a thin rod. You replace it with two equal and opposite forces in the free body diagram.